# How to recover closed form on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a project in Visual Studio. I had two (design) forms open along with the code for each form. But I accidentally closed one of the design forms and I dont know how to get it back and I hadn't saved it yet. Is there a way to recover the design form?

Comment: I have the code window open for the design form deleted by the way.

Comment: Double click it in solution explorer?

Comment: If you really hadn't saved it, no, there is no way to get back what you didn't save. But it seems you did.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend keeping the Solution Explorer open so you can see all the files within your project(s).  You can then right click on a file within the Solution Explorer that represents a form and then select either 'View Design' or 'View Code' to open up either the Form Designer for that file, or your code behind.

Answer (score 2):

If your code file of this form is opened, just press `Shift+F7`

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I thought I was gonna have to do it all over again.

Answer (score 1):

menu -> VIEW -> Solution Explorer there are all your files. Double click on the file you want to edit. Maybe keep solution explorer opened.